# How to use CStatRelation in Yii

Tags: sql, yii, entity-relationship

I am trying to find a way to collect data using **sql** aggregate functions like *max*, *min* and *count*.

And I found that *CStatRelation* class seems to be what I want. [CStatRelation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStatRelation) doc

It can be used in the *relation* function in Yii's model class.

The usage is like this:

```
class SomeModelClass extends CActiveRecord{

 public function relations() {

        return array(
            'bidCount'=>array(self::STAT,'Bid','auction_id'),//it can be used like this


        );
    }
}
```

The default value of the *rowCount* in the example code is the *count(*)*. But what if I want to find the *max/min* value of a specific column??

How can I modify the code to retrieve the max or the min??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'maxBid' => array(self::STAT, 'Bid', 'auction_id', 'select'=>'MAX(bid_amount)'),
```

Comment: I've had some problems with Yii's stat queries. There are still a [few](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=2494) [open](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=2554) [issues](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=1244). In some cases, it is more robust and versatile to write: `function getMaxBid() { return Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT MAX(bid_amount) FROM Bid")->queryScalar(); }`.
You can then use `$bid->maxBid` in the wame way.